# Java servlets: Setting HTTP status code doesn't work with TomCat 6

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, tomcat6

I'm simply trying to set HTTP status code for the Http Servlet Response. And this works perfectly in development with TomCat 7. But on the customers server, which runs TomCat6 (6.0.36) the command is simply ignored.

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
```

I even tried to do a

```
 response.flushBuffer();
```

to commit the setStatus, but with no luck.

What am I missing? According to the [TomCat 6.0 docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/ResponseFacade.html#setStatus(int)) the `setStatus()` works just the same as in [version 7](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/ResponseFacade.html#setStatus(int)).

Obviously one solution is to upgrade the clients TomCat server, but we want to avoid that.

-Thank you.

Comment: For the document you linked " This method is used to set the return status code `when there is no error`"

Comment: @markbernard: I know. And I would love to use it the right way.
And as @user2533521 suggest. Which is the correct way. Unfortunately sendError redirects the user to a 404-page. 

All though `setStatus()` is depreciated for errors, it works flawlessly. And I made it work for TC6 by rising the `setBufferSize()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use HttpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); You may want to give this a try.